# backup and restore using just sqlserver is it possible?

Tags: 2010

backup and restore sharepoint 2010  using just sqlserver is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly back up just config and content databases, and restore them back in using database attach, but you will miss any customisations such as features which have been deployed to the filesystem.

Comment: is there a link/article(s) which explains the process

Comment: The process is similar to performing an upgrade, using the "database attach" method, details here, and also around on google if you search for "Database attach SharePoint": http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e8b66eb3-27c7-4a39-a2e1-3e7d18b12ee1 - Also, have a look out for third party vendors who provide SharePoint backup utilies, like AvePoint (I do not work for AvePoint nor have I tried their backup products).